# Merge two Entity Framework queries into one

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two queries in one method. The difference between them is that when `organizationId` passed in the method is not null you should look up by `organizationId`. When the `organizationId` is null in the method, then retrieve all operations by `phoneNumber` and with `organizationId` null. See the following:

```
public async Task<decimal> CalculateDifferenceBetweenEntriesAndConsummations(string? phoneNumber,
    int? organizationId)
{
    if (organizationId != null)
    {
        return await _dbContext.signumid_credit_operation
                               .Where(x => x.OrganizationId == organizationId && 
                                           (x.OperationType == OperationType.Purchase || x.OperationType == OperationType.Refund))
                               .SumAsync(x => x.Amount)
               - await _dbContext.signumid_credit_operation
                                 .Where(x => x.OrganizationId == organizationId && x.OperationType == OperationType.Consummation)
                                 .SumAsync(x => x.Amount);
    }

    return await _dbContext.signumid_credit_operation
                           .Where(x => x.PhoneNumber == phoneNumber && (x.OperationType == OperationType.Purchase || x.OperationType == OperationType.Refund) && x.OrganizationId == null)
                           .SumAsync(x => x.Amount)
           - await _dbContext.signumid_credit_operation
                             .Where(x => x.PhoneNumber == phoneNumber && x.OperationType == OperationType.Consummation && x.OrganizationId == null)
                             .SumAsync(x => x.Amount);
}
```

I would like to have only one `return` in this method combining the queries and still doing the same job.

Is that possible?

Comment: Can't you just use the first query and be done? If `organizationId` is `null` then the first query becomes the second query anyway. I'm not completely sure that EF handles nullable value types that way but I would expect it would. Oh, I just realised that `phoneNumber` isn't used in the first query.

Comment: By the way, this question has nothing at all to do with ASP.NET. The fact that the code is used in an ASP.NET application is irrelevant when it's a service method that would be exactly the same in any application. Please only apply tags that are directly relevant to the specific problem.

Comment: @user18387401, no because there is phoneNumber in the second query.

Comment: I realised that just before you replied but I was too slow.

Comment: @user18387401 I agree about the tags

Answer (score 0):

I would think this should work:

```cs
.Where(x => ((organizationId != null &&
              x.OrganizationId == organizationId) ||
             (organizationId == null &&
              x.OrganizationId == null &&
              x.PhoneNumber == phoneNumber)) &&
```

Actually, I think that should simplify to this:

```cs
.Where(x => x.OrganizationId == organizationId &&
            (organizationId != null || x.PhoneNumber == phoneNumber) &&
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the common predicate in a variable:

```
public async Task<decimal> CalculateDifferenceBetweenEntriesAndConsummations(string? phoneNumber,
    int? organizationId)
{

    var baseQuery = _dbContext.signumid_credit_operation;

    if (organizationId != null)
    {
        baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(x => x.OrganizationId == organizationId);
    }
    else
    {
        baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(x => x.PhoneNumber == phoneNumber && x.OrganizationId == null);
    }

    return await baseQuery.Where(x=> x.OperationType == OperationType.Purchase || x.OperationType == OperationType.Refund)
                          .SumAsync(x => x.Amount) - 
           await baseQuery.Where(x=> x.OperationType == OperationType.Consummation)
                          .SumAsync(x => x.Amount);
}
```